# Expression in power BI

Tags: expression, powerbi, qliksense

I have this expression which is in qlik sense syntax now i want to change / convert this into power bi dax syntax.. how i do that

```
  if([Curency] = 'USD',
((Sum({< Fiscal_Year = {'2016','2017'},[Type_Billing] ={'N2','Z2'}>}[BSMA])
/Sum({< Fiscal_Year = {'2016','2017'},[Type_Billing] ={'N2','Z2'}>}[BSA_NETWR]))*vCurrency),
Sum({< Fiscal_Year = {'2016','2017'},[Type_Billing] ={'N2','Z2'}>}[BSMA])
/Sum({< Fiscal_Year = {'2016','2017'},[Type_Billing] ={'N2','Z2'}>}[BSA_NETWR]))
```

note : currenlty i dont have any power bi  file

Comment: can you possibly explain what this measure is doing?

Comment: this is dividing if currency is USD  THEN divided (bsma/bsa_netwr) * vcurrency and  (bsma/bsa_netwr) one is with vcurrency and the other is without currency .. on the bases of mentioned filters

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
VAR USDFilter = 
CALCULATE(
    FILTER(
        ALL('your_table_name'),
        'your_table_name'[Curency] = "USD"
    )
)

VAR Numerator = 
SUMX(
    USDFilter,
    USDFilter[BSMA]
)

VAR Denominator = 
SUMX(
    USDFilter,
    USDFilter[BSA_NETWR]
)

VAR Result = 
IF(
    COUNTROWS(USDFilter) > 0,
    (Numerator / Denominator) * [vCurrency],
    (Numerator / Denominator)
)

RETURN Result
```

To transcribe code languages, Bard and Chat GPT are a good option.